# TailwindCSS does not work after installation

Tags: npm, installation, config, tailwind-css, postcss

I have installed tailwindcss via npm (using postcss) and configured files as per [installation guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss). However, the tailwind css shows no effect and does not apply any style to the page. Codes of config files can be found below:

**postcss.config.js**

```
   module.exports = {
      plugins: {
        tailwindcss: { config: './tailwindcss-config.js' },
        autoprefixer: {},
      },
    }
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
  module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**globals.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Do all of your file names line up? You're referencing a 'tailwindcss-config.js' in your postcss config file yet you've listed the file name as being 'tailwind.config.js'. Which is correct? How are you running TailWind? What does your projects folder structure look like?

Comment: @NathanDawson I followed the installation guide and when it wasn't working I referenced it in postcss config file. I am running tailwind in my nodejs project and it has been intsalled by npm and it resides in node modules folder, but the tailwind config and postcss config files are not in any sub folders.

Answer (score 0):

Tailwindcss Installation Using PostCSS

Step-1.Create folder

Step-2.Open Build-in terminal in VS code

Step-3.for installation

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
```

Step-4.To create tailwind.config.js

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

Step-5.create a file as postcss.config.js and paste this code

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

Step-6.Add content in tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./public/**/*.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Step-7.Create new folder as tailwind

In this folder create file as main.css and paste this code

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Step-8.In Terminal put

```
npm init -y
```

Step-9.Open package.json

near script put as

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "tailwind build -i tailwind/main.css -o public/tailwind.css",
  "watch": "tailwind build -i tailwind/main.css -o public/tailwind.css -w"
},
```

Step-10.In Terminal put as

```
npm run build
```

and

```
npm run watch
```

Step-11.In public folder create file as index.html

and Finally

Step-12.In index.html

link tailwind.css file as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tailwind.css">
```

and continue your script